# Gantry Joomla template configuration error

Tags: php, templates, joomla

I've a problem with framework gantry installed as joomla theme. First time I tried install the template on a free webhosting for testing(altervista.org PHP 5.2.17 ) and everything worked well.

Then I transfered all my web site on another webhosting (not-free) register.it
The web site work well, it display with no error, but inside the administrator, if i want to enter in template configuration it display this:

```
Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class GantryFormGroup in /htdocs/public/www/libraries/gantry/core/config/gantryformhelper.class.php on line 100
```

this is altervista.org info:

```
Versione database    5.1.49-community-log
Collation database   utf8_general_ci
Versione PHP     5.2.17
Web Server   Apache
WebServer interfaccia PHP    apache2handler
Versione di Joomla!  Joomla! 2.5.6 Stable [ Ember ] 19-June-2012 14:00 GMT
Versione piattaforma Joomla!     Joomla Platform 11.4.0 Stable [ Brian Kernighan ] 03-Jan-2012 00:00 GMT
User Agent   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4
```

and this is register.it info:

```
PHP attivo su    Linux opus19 2.6.39.4 #1 SMP Tue Jun 19 17:52:27 CEST 2012 x86_64
Versione database    5.1.44-enterprise-gpl-advanced-log
Collation database   utf8_general_ci
Versione PHP     5.3.3-7+squeeze3
Web Server   Apache/2.2.14 (Unix)
WebServer interfaccia PHP    cgi-fcgi
Versione di Joomla!  Joomla! 2.5.6 Stable [ Ember ] 19-June-2012 14:00 GMT
Versione piattaforma Joomla!     Joomla Platform 11.4.0 Stable [ Brian Kernighan ] 03-Jan-2012 00:00 GMT
User Agent   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4
```

All the other administrator back-end work, but how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that PHP 5.2.4 is the minimum requirements (which you meet).

But PHP 5.3+ is recommended.

See [Joomla! Technical requirements](http://docs.joomla.org/Technical_requirements)

Answer (score -1):

When ever moving Gantry to the new host you need to clear cache of Gantry.
So just navigate to Site=>Maintenance=> Clear Cache  ... and clear cache of Gantry, Gantry Admin, Gantry Less ..

Comment: solved. I've updated gantry framework to last version 4.1.2 :)

Comment: This post would be better suited as a comment on the original post.